# tensorflow serving request error, {The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [1] }

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am new to tensorflow serving, here's the data I post:

```
data_0 = {'inputs/input_x': mfcc[0], "inputs/is_training":False, "inputs/keep_prob":1}

data = json.dumps({"signature_name":'serving_default', 'instances':[data_0]})

headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}

json_response = requests.post(URL, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I got an error which comes from the `is_training` flag of batch normalization (and I think the same for the dropout rate):

```
{ "error": "The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [1]\n\t [[{{node conv_layer2/conv2/batch_normalization/cond/Switch}}]]" }
```

Then I saw a similar issue and modified my code into

```
data_0 = {'inputs/input_x': mfcc[0], "inputs/is_training":[False], "inputs/keep_prob":[1]}
```

Then I got one more dimension:

```
{ "error": "The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [1,1]\n\t [[{{node conv_layer2/conv2/batch_normalization/cond/Switch}}]]" }
```

And I tried to post without `[]` like :

```
data = json.dumps({"signature_name":'serving_default', 'instances':data_0})
```

I got :

```
"error": "JSON Value:{...}  Excepting \'instances\' to be an list/array" }
```

Informations of my model:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs/input_x'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 34, 20)
        name: inputs/input_x:0
    inputs['inputs/is_training'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_BOOL
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: inputs/is_training:0
    inputs['inputs/keep_prob'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: inputs/keep_prob:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['Softmax'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: Softmax:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Need some help here, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is  just about the bool type? Do you have an idea please @zzachimonde  ?

Answer (score 0):

For now I haven't got an answer and I re-trained my model without `is_training` flag, and that works.

So it's maybe that there is a problem about boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

When using `instances` as input key, all inputs should have same 0-th dimension. Try `inputs` instead of `instances`. For example,

```
data = json.dumps({"signature_name":'serving_default', 'inputs':data_0})
```